# View history of Chrome "Send to your devices"

Tags: google-chrome

As explained [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/9430554), Google Chrome can send pages from one device (computer or phone) to another. However, if you view the shared page and navigate away, the sent page stops being accessible. Is there a way to view the history of pages you have used "Send to your devices" on?